# Link to history in a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to link to chrome://history page in a button of an extension I'm working, but with `href="chrome://history"` the console says `Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://history/`

What can I do?

Thanks and greetings

**Edited:**

I'm trying with this:

The button I want to trigger with the event has .btn-history class.

In **content.js**:

```
function messaging(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({command: "openHistory"});
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-history')[0].addEventListener('click', messaging);
});
```

In **background.js**:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(command == "openHistory") {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'chrome://history'});
  }
});
```

But doesn't work.

Comment: See the documentation for chrome.tabs.create, it can open chrome:// URLs.

Comment: How can I trigger a link to `chrome.tabs.create({url: "chrome://history"});` ?

Comment: Use the standard method: attach a click event listener.

Comment: check the edited please.

Comment: It should be `if (message.command ==`

Comment: Thanks! Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, you can have a button in your html, like so:

```
<button id="historyBtn">History</button>
```

And in your javascript you can use define an event handler for the button using jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $("#historyBtn").click(function(){
     chrome.tabs.create({url: "chrome://history"}); 
   });
});
```

If you would like to change the currently active tab to open history, you can replace the `chrome.tabs.create` line in the above snippet with something like:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {    
   chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, { url: "chrome://history" });
});
```

Hope this helps :)